# Question about the existence of sets

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

If there is a sequence of set $a_{i}$ and $i \in I \wedge |I|>|\mathbb{R}|$, is the set $A$ which $\forall i (i \in I \rightarrow a_{i}\in A)$ and the set $\bigcup \limits_{i \in \mathbb{R}} a_{i}$ exists? And how to proof it by using the axioms of ZF(Zermelo-Frankel)C(axiom of choice)?

Comment: Separation + Union?

Comment: We also need Infinity and Power set to guarantee there is a set of reals. (Power set is overkill, I know.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we assume that $(a_i)_{i\in I} = \{(i, a_i) \space|\space i \in I\} = \{\{\{i\},\{i,a_i\}\}\space|\space i\in I\}=: A_I$ is an existing set, we can construct $$X_1 := \bigcup A_I = \{\{i\},\{i,a_i\}\space |\space i\in I\}$$
by the axiom of union and likewise may construct $$ X_2 := \bigcup X_1 = \{i,a_i \space | \space i\in I\} $$

Now we already can construct your set $A$ as $$ A:= \{x\in  X_2 \space | \space \exists i\in I.(\{\{i\},\{i,x\}\} \in A_I)\} = \{a_i \space | \space i \in I\}$$
by the axiom of separation and the axiom of pairing (for the sets $\{i\},\{i,x\}$ and $\{\{i\},\{i,x\}\}$).

If we interprete $\bigcup_{i\in \mathbb{R}}a_i$ as $\bigcup_{i\in \mathbb{R}\cap I}a_i$ we can write this similarly as
$$
\bigcup \{x\in X_2 \space | \space \exists i\in (I\cap \mathbb{R}).(\{\{i\},\{i,x\}\} \in A_I)\}
$$
again using the axiom of union and separation as well as the axiom of pairing.

Comment: To the proposer: In the  formal language of ZF there is no  word "set".  Things that satisfy  conditions  stated in the formal language are asserted to exist, or asserted to not exist. There are other foundational formulations in which you can say "$x$ is a set", but not in ZF.

Comment: What if the sequence $a_{i}$ is a collection? Can we still proof that?

Comment: To the proposer: "Collection" is an informal word, like "family", which for  a set-theorist are just synonyms for "set". And in ZF,  everything that exists is a set.